# Using std::forward with a non-forwarding, plain old reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Asking for a friend:

Why does `std::forward` in the following code cast the parameter `c` to an rvalue ?

```
template <typename T>
void f (T& c) {
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference_t<T>; 
    std::vector<value_type> v; 
    // debugger reveals: push_back( T&& value ) is called here  
    v.push_back(std::forward<T>(c));
}
```

Note that `c` is not a universal/forwarding reference here. I am aware of the fact that this function would most probably be of more use if it actually was, but curious all the same.

Comment: "*Note that c is not a universal/forwarding reference here.*" So *why* are you using `std::forward`?

Comment: I accidentally omitted one ampersand and was just wondering why std::forward behaves the way it does here.

Comment: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this situation, you have to understand why forwarding references work.  Given a definition like

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) {}
```

when you write something like

```
some_type some_object;
foo(some_object);
```

template deduction deduces `T` to be `some_type&`.  Now the parameter `t` has the type `some_type& &&`.  Since you can't have references to references, [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) rules are applied and `some_type& &&` is collapsed to `some_type&`.

If, instead, you write something like

```
some_type some_object;
foo(std::move(some_object));
```

template deduction deduces `T` to be `some_type`.  Now the parameter `t` has the type `some_type&&`.  That's a perfectly valid type, so no reference collapsing is done.

Now we get to `std::forward`.  All `std::forward<U>` does is cast its parameter to `U&&`.  If `U` is `some_type`, as in the second case above, the parameter is cast to `some_type&&`.  It remains an rvalue-reference.  If `U` is `some_type&`, as in the first case above, reference collapsing is performed again, and `some_type& &&` becomes `some_type&`.  So `std::forward` returns an lvalue-reference.

So the ultimate answer to your original question is that the return type of `std::forward` only depends on the type passed as `std::forward`'s template parameter.  Since `T` in your case will always be deduced as a non-reference type, `std::forward` will always return an rvalue-reference.

Comment: Accepted for being the most detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

`std::forward<T>(c)` is equivalent to `static_cast<T&&>(c)`.

If `T&&` is a forwarding reference then this allows an lvalue to be forwarded as an lvalue because `T` will be deduced as an lvalue reference type and `T&&` will be the same lvalue reference type by the reference-collapsing rules. In your situation, `T&&` is not a forwarding reference, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the definition of `std::forward<T>(x)` is to cast `x` to type `T&&`. If you pass a non-reference as argument you’ll get an rvalue reference `T&&` back. Since your `T` cannot be a reference type (you cannot have a reference to a reference), it must be a non-reference type.